# After Effects Change expression variable from JSX

Tags: jsx, extendscript, after-effects

I'm trying to edit variable (txt) in expression that located inside "Source Text" (Text Layer). How can I get access to it from JSX file?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
var comp = app.project.activeItem;
comp.layer(0).text.sourceText.expression = "txt = "new text""
```